# Is encoding XML in Go using "innerxml" only meant to be used with certain types?

Tags: xml, go, encoding

When using `xml:",innerxml"` I see different results depending on the type being "inlined"

When using *string* it works as expected but changing the type to *int* the value gets wrapped in another tag.

Minimal example on [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/pXvcqF6sTs7).

I was expected the structure om produced XML to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get your "desired" output only if the field's type is `string` or `[]byte`. This isn't documented at `xml.Marshal()` properly, but the documentation of [`xml.Unmarshal()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Unmarshal) does mention it:

> Unmarshal maps an XML element to a struct using the following rules. In the rules, the tag of a field refers to the value associated with the key 'xml' in the struct field's tag (see the example above).
>
> - If the struct has a field of type []byte or string with tag ",innerxml", Unmarshal accumulates the raw XML nested inside the element in that field. The rest of the rules still apply.

Comment: This was the documentation I was looking for. Thanks.